# Morphia query in embedded list

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

my issue is to query a complex element.

```
@Entity("Activity")
public class Activity extends BaseEntity {
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private Date deadline;
        private Boolean completed;
        @Embedded
        private List<SubActivity> listSubActivity;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

where

```
@Entity("SubActivity")
public class SubActivity extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private Date deadline;
    private Boolean completed;
.
.
.
}
```

I have to find all activities with sub-activities expired.
I try with

```
Query<Activity> queryA = datastore.createQuery(Activity.class);
queryA.and(
   queryA.criteria("deadline").lessThan(today), // where today is a Date()
   queryA.criteria("completed").equal(false)
 );
```

but it does not work because retrieve also this activity

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("581352597dfd063decb0b357"),
  "className" : "com.etherweaver.collections.Activity",
  "name" : "Name",
  "description" : "description",
  "deadline" : ISODate("2016-11-02T23:00:00.000Z"),
  "completed" : true,
  "listSubActivity" : [{
      "name" : "sub activity 1",
      "deadline" : ISODate("2016-11-01T23:00:00.000Z"), 
      "completed" : true 
    }, {
      "name" : "sub activity 2",
      "deadline" : ISODate("2016-11-06T23:00:00.000Z"),
      "completed" : false
    }, {
      "name" : "sub activity 3",
      "deadline" : ISODate("2016-11-06T23:00:00.000Z"),
      "completed" : true
    }]
}
```

where sub activity 1 is expired but completed.

Is there is a method to query the list embedded with conditions verified line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
Query<SubActivity> query = datastore.createQuery(SubActivity.class)
        .filter("deadline < ", new Date())
        .filter("completed = ", true);

List<Activity> activities = datastore.find(Activity.class)
                                              .field("listSubActivity")
                                              .elemMatch(query)
                                              .asList();
```

**Update**

To use hasThisElement, it only allows equals comparison not other conditional comparison.

So I'm not sure if this is going to work for you ,but sorry, I don't see any other way right now.

```
SubActivity filter = new SubActivity();
filter.setDeadline(new Date());
filter.setCompleted(true);

List<Activity> activities = datastore.find(Activity.class)
                                              .field("listSubActivity")
                                              .hasThisElement(filter)
                                              .asList();
```

**Update 2**

Aggregation based approach - This approach will filter the rows based on the query.

```
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Group.*;

Query<Activity> query = datastore.createQuery(Activity.class)
               .filter("listSubActivity.deadline < ", anyDate)
               .filter("listSubActivity.completed = ", true);

Iterator<Activity> activities = datastore.createAggregation(Activity.class).
               unwind("listSubActivity").
               match(query).
               group("_id", grouping("className", first("className")),
                       grouping("name", first("name")),
                       grouping("description", first("description")),
                       grouping("deadline", first("deadline")),
                       grouping("completed", first("completed")), grouping("listSubActivity", push("listSubActivity"))).aggregate(Activity.class);
```

Comment: The method _.elemMatch(query)_ don't exist

Comment: elemMatch is there in the snapshot version. updated to use hasThisElement. Cant test it right now. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the correct approach, but method _hasThisElement_ needs an Object, not a Query.

Comment: Ok, this works fine, but I need to find all expired subactivities.
    _filter.setDeadline(new Date());_
let me find subactivities expired in a particolar date, not all before today.

Comment: Updated based on the feedback. Hope it helps.

Comment: GREAT!!!
I had to change the Iterator statement using _Group.grouping()_ and _Group.first()_ and now it works perfectly.

Thanks a lot ^_^